# ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor on linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, listener, tnsnames, linux

I have configured oracle 12c on Rhel 7. When I try to connect database using following command it gets connected with no issues:

```
sqlplus system/Forest123@orcl
```

I'm facing problem when I try to put the connection string with `hostname` and `port` as shown below:

```
sqlplus system/Forest123@localhost:1521/orcl
```

Error occurred is

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I have gone through the questions asked before, but none of them helped me solve this problem.

Following are my `tnsnames.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` and `listener.ora` files.

**tnsnames.ora**

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle_12C.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.localdomain)
    )
  )
```

**listener.ora**

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracle_12C.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1 localhost4
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
::127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
172.31.15.86 oracle_12C.localdomain oracle_12C
```

Comment: Post the output of `$lsnrctl status listener`.

Comment: Why do you want to put the `hostname` and `port` in the connection string?

Comment: Does ``sqlplus system/Forest123@localhost:1521/orcl.localdomain`` work? Your service name is usually suffixed by your domain. Your tnsnames.ora entry connects to orcl.localdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the following error message that mean either `hostname` is not correct and/or the domain you are using.

How to know if everything is working fine or not?
You need to execute `hostname` command, lets say the output is `oracle_12C`, and execute `cat /etc/resolve.con` lets say the domain name `mydomain.com`, then you need to edit `/etc/hosts` like the following

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1 localhost4
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
::127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
172.31.15.86 oracle_12C.mydomin.com oracle_12C
```

Note if you are **not** using domain then `/etc/hosts/` should be like the following

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain
127.0.0.1 localhost4
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
::127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
172.31.15.86 oracle_12C
```

Now lets move to `tnsnames.ora`, inside this file you need to search for your database section (in your question orcl) replace it like the following (note you need to take a backup from this file before doing any changes):

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname as /etc/hosts>)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
      )
```

Note for host if you have doming then `HOST = oracle_12C.mydomain.com`, else it should be `HOST = oracle_12C`

Now save the file and close it.

After that lets move to `listener.ora`,  take a backup from it and edit it like the following:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <hostname as /etc/hosts>)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Now restart your listener by executing `lsnrctl stop` and `lsnrctl start` then try to connect to the database by using the following commands

```
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
sqlplus system/Forest123
```

Answer (score 2):

Below process is solved my problem.

1. Connect to server using **sqlplus / as sysdba** command
2. check whether local listener exists or not by using **SQL> show parameter local_listener** command. For me local_listener value is empty
3. set the listener dynamically by using
   **SQL> alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=LOCALHOST)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;** command
4. Then do register by using alter command **SQL> alter system register;**
5. Now check whether listener is added or not **SQL> show parameter local_listener**.
   Now listener is added successfully with 
   Value = **(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=LOCALHOST)(PORT=1521))**
6. After adding local listener I am able to connect successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your host should be 0.0.0.0 in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

Also you must register your SID_name in listner.ora as mentioned below.
for example if your SID_NAME is ORCLCDB, listener.ora should look like this.

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCLCDB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )
```

The tnsnames.ora file should look like this.

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCLCDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below worked for me:

- Checked services using `services.msc`
- Restarted the services `OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener` and `OracleServiceORCL`

After that connected using SQL developer. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error I realized that my hostname entry was incorrect in /etc/hosts file.

Before encountering this error I had changed the hostname of the machine from, lets say my-hostname to my-hostname2. Later I changed it back to my-hostname but the in /etc/hosts the entry was still my-hostname2 and that caused the problem while trying to resolve the ip address in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora

Answer (score -1):

datasource:
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain

```
username: SYS as SYSDBA

password: Oradoc_db1
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; please explain or delete it.